# Getting all the values of a Datagrid Row into Comboboxes

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I am currently trying to get all the values of a Datagridview Row into multiple Comboboxes. There are ten (theoretically up to 20) cells that need to be read and send to multiple comboboxes. I am experimenting with using this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int numberofcolumns = data.Columns.Count;

       CBKaNr.Items.Clear();

       for (int i = 0; i >= numberofcolumns; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Selected = true;
                CBKaNr.Items.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value.ToString());
```

(Example using only 1 Box because of readability)

I tried finding the problematic part with a `Messagebox.Show` which suggested that the Problem begins after the `for` Statement.

For Context (how the program is supposed to work):

The program reads an excel File, shows it in a DataGridView and when you click on a Row of the Datagrid the Values of each Cell are supposed to load into multiple Comboboxes. The user then selects the wanted value and the program reads the shown value of the comboboxes and converts that into a Text File, which can then be read by some kind of printer. This is the Data in the Excel sheet (one of the rows in question):

[image]

Everything works except for the before-mentioned problem.

Is there an easy way out of this?

Comment: Index is 0 based. So if you have a count `numberofcolumns` of 5 you will have the indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, so accessing the 5th index is invalid which you are doing here: `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[numberofcolumns]` - you will need a `for` loop from 0 to exclusive 5.

Comment: @RandRandom so like this? 

                for (int i = 0; i >= 20; i++)

                {
                    CBKaNr.Items.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value.ToString());

Comment: Why `<=` ? look here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ClEUkP check the output at the bottom of the page and you will see `20` so you wrote inclusive for loop and you will again run into `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because there will be no 20th index. Why hardcoded 20 instead of `numberofcolumns` ?

Comment: @RandRandom just changed the < to > ... noticed it a sec before you answered... I changed the 20 to `numberofcolumns` ... I'm pretty new to c# so I don't really know what I'm doing yet. Thanks for the answer tho. The Program works now :D

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: @RandRandom sry to bother again, but after some fiddeling around, the program doesn't fill my comboboxes. I only added an ´if´ case just in case of ´null´ values and my code that should add the values into the box basically looks the same as it did in my original problem, but ´numberofcolumns´ is replaced by ´i´. Any Idea what the Problem might be?

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code, and I will have a look at what is wrong.

Comment: @RandRandom changed the question

Comment: Well you still have `<=` (inclusive) instead of just `<` (exclusive). Other from that I don't see an issue. edit: actually you still have `<` and `>` mixed up.

Comment: @RandRandom ... yeah... thanks for the answer, these two `<`  `>` are always a headache for me. Big Thanks! It now works as intended ^^